# Query performances with $in and $nin mongodb at scale

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 3 collections :

- users
- mappers
- seens

Here is a document in `users` where "_id" is the id of a `user` and the `ids` array contains a list of other `users` `_id` :

```
{
  _id: "uid",
  ids: [
     "uid0",
     "uid5",
     ...
     "uid100"
  ]
}
```

A document in `seens` looks exactly like the one in `users` but in the `ids` array, there are ids of `mappers` that have been seen by the user, the "_id" is the one of the user owner of the `array`.

Here is a `mapper` where "_id" is the ID of a `user` and `map.id` is an `id` potentially existing in the `ids` field of a document of `seens` :

```
{
  _id: "uid",
  at: 1453592,
  map: {
    id: "uid",
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve all `mappers` that meet some conditions :

- `_id` must be in the `ids` of the `user`
- `at` must be `$lt` now and `$gt` than a given value (that is lower than now)
- `map.id` must not be in `ids` of the `seens` of the `user`

The query looks like this :

```
{
  "_id": {"$in": ids},
  "$and": [
    {"at": {"$lt": now}},
    {"at": {"$gt": start_date}},
    {"map.id": {"$nin": seens}}
   ],
},
```

Where `ids` is the array of the user ids and `seens` is the array of the mappers already seen.

I have done some experiment on this query, it's working very fine with a thousands of records.

However, if i have 10 000 `ids`, 10 000 `seens` and 10 000 `mappers` and performing this query, it takes 15seconds.
I have added an index on : at (descending) and map.id (ascending), it now takes 8sec.

I simply know that if my collections scale, this is only takes longer and longer.

How can i make it always returning results in less than 1sec not matter how many documents i have in my collections ?
The underlying question is how to keep the query efficiency using `$in` and `$nin` at scale ?